# Get specific list of collections from Mongo

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a collection in mongo DB with document consisting of movies ,series and product details . Format as below : { productname, productid , movies : [{movie1},{movie2} ] , series: [{series1},{series2} ] } 
I want to get only movies with a product id . Currently able to apply filter by product id and get entire document but the document will contain even series . How can i restrict to get only movies?

Im using the below projection, so i can get only movies from DB:
Builders.Projection.Include("movies");
 but using above im getting document as  {movies: [{movie1},{movie2}]} 
Im looking for something like {[{movie1},{movie2} ]} so i can deserialize directly to List .
I think i need to give some more detail in projection. can anyone please help with the same.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo is a Document database, so the result of any operation (any number of aggregations) will always be a document/BSON. i don't think you can avoid having a key. alternatively you need to handle it in the client side code base...

Comment: Also, i verifies , that even after using project to include only ovies, im even getting productname ,productid too. How can i use project to get only Movies ignoring all other fields .

Comment: I am not familiar with c# but there should be a way to perform aggregation. But projection on find should do the same. Would you be able to provide that piece of code..and a sample document